# Smart Outlet wiring- (GWB to GWBO)

Tags: wiring, receptacle, socket

I have bought a smart outlet which has only three wires (Green, White, Black), however, the wiring available in my condo has four wires. I would appreciate it if you could help me in properly setting up the outlet.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo that looks into the back of the outlet box please?

Comment: I have added a new picture to the post. Also, forgot to mention this in my post but there is another outlet on the left hand side of the one shown, not sure if that information is useful. I live in Canada which has a different color coding system for wires compared to the US. Thanks @ThreePhaseEel.

Comment: Eh, Canada and US wire color coding isn't *that* different -- what you have is a *conduit job*, which lets the electrician pull out the fancy colors to suit, more or less ;)

Comment: Also, is the tab on the hot side of the existing receptacle intact, or broken off?

Comment: Tab on hot side broken but intact on the neutral side.

Comment: Which half of the receptacle is controlled by the existing switch(es)? I'm guessing it's the top, but I'm not 100% sure

Comment: Top half is controlled by a switch.

Comment: Are there light fixtures in the room already, whether controlled by that switch or a different switch?

Comment: You have a receptacle partly controlled by a switch. Which half is switched? What do you expect to do with the existing switch?

Comment: No light fixtures in the room, my guess is that the switch only controls the top half of the the two outlets (the one shown in the pictures and one on its left ). I am going to leave the switch where it is but based on the above discussion my guess is that you are going to say if I install the smart outlet there the switch will be rendered useless which I am ok with.

Comment: Code is not OK with that, though.  You know how you can go into almost any room anywhere, grope around in "the usual place" and most likely find a light switch?  *That's not by accident*.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Thank you for pointing out code issues.

Comment: What make and model of smart outlet are you using, and are you wedded to that specific unit, or would you be willing to consider alternatives?

Comment: It is a Kasa/TP-link K200, not attached to it at all, can return it if necessary. I would appreciate any recommendations for an alternative.

Comment: @X_Novichok_X -- do you still want always-hot power to be available at this point?